# How to determine each DocumentSnapshot without retrieving DocumentSnapshot stored in the list

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the case of List , if this list is printed, it becomes Instance of DocumentSnapshot and the contents cannot be seen.
Of course, you can identify each DocumentSnapshot by specifying it with [] and looking at the .id property. 
Is there a way to determine without taking it out?

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you try to clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to approach and determine the documentSnapshot and json responses you should checkout your database structures and should use print logs.

For Ex :

If you receive a snapshot for your query, you can determine the values by print logs.

```
print(snapshot);
print(snapshot.data);
// by knowing the runtime types you can manage different data accordingly.
print(snapshot.data.runtimeType);
```

In this way every time by checking snapshot's runtimeType you can easily determine list, map and data type values.

For Ex: if snapshot.data's runtime type is a map then to manage map key-value pairs you can follow the approach like,

```
Map map=snapshot.data;

map.forEach((key,value){
      print("key : ${key}");
      print("value : ${value}");
    });
```

This way you will be able to print out the logs for map key-value pairs.

Similarly, if to manage list kind of snapshots then,

```
List list=snapshot.data;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  print("list : ${list[i]}");
  print("list : ${list[i].runtimeType}");
}
```

This way you can easily manage any kind of json formats and snapshots.